# SharePoint certification 70-331 vs 70-448

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, administration, certification

Currently I am working on SharePoint 2013 environment for over a year!

I am willing to get the SharePoint certification and I want to know the difference between the 70-331 and the 70-488 certifications!

Please suggest the best SharePoint 2013 certifications to prove my skills and  which one I should go first?

Comment: Don't you mean 70-488? 70-448 is about MS SQL Server 2008...

Comment: Yes I am updating my question, I mean 70-488

Answer (score 6):

**70-331 ([Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-331.aspx))** is about installing, configuring and maintaining a SharePoint farm. It's not about *developing* solutions (despite the name); it's about administration.
Note: it's not a SharePoint end-user certification, it's an *admin* one.

**70-488 ([Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-488.aspx))** is about dev and customizations. So it's all about WSP solutions development, add-ins (apps), Visual Studio, features, C#, server and client APIs, etc.

So, are you a dev or an IT guy?! :)

Comment: Thank you @Evariste for your quick answer!! I think I need tp prepare for the 70-488 certification since I am a SharePoint Developer.  However I have a question for you: As you see [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/learning/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx) There are 4 exams, am I obliged to pass the "Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3" and "Developing ASP.NET MVC Web Applications" exams before going to the SP core solutions 2013 ?? or I can go directly to the SharePoint??